# Syncing Two Files

Tags: include

I am creating two documents: 1 is a set of homeworks and the other is their solutions. Each homework and solution set is its own `.tex` file and there is a master `.tex` for the HW-booklet and another for the Answers-booklet. I'd like the flexibility so that I can change the order of the homework assignments and the same will be done "automatically" in the answers document.

I am using `\include` to insert each assignment and right now I have something like

```
\include{Ass1}

\include{Ass2}

\include{Ass3}
```

and then in the answers I need to write

```
\include{Ans1}

\include{Ans2}

\include{Ans3}
```

Is there a way to have a third file (something like a make file) where I choose the order like 3,1,2 and then each document (the homework and the answers) both use this ordering to include their files in the "right" order so all I have to do is recompile their main `.tex` files? I do know how to make make files (ha!) so maybe an easy to follow example could help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are the `\include` statements consecutively, i.e. nothing else between? Are the names `Ass1, Ass2,` etc. i.e. with this prefix?

Comment: have you considered making just a single "driver" file that selects one or the other option (problem or solution) to choose which "item" file to input depending on a switch set at the beginning?

Comment: I'm flexible with respect to how the include statements are written, currently they are consecutive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution relies on a naming scheme both for assignment and answer files. It fetches the external `AssX.tex` in the specified order with `\include` and saves the order to a `\clist` variable.

At any place later on, the `\getallsolutions` command replaces the prefix given as the first argument with the (assumed) answer prefix, i.e. `AssX` becomes `AnsX` then and tries to load those files!

This can be set than in some external file, say, `order.tex` and input this `order.tex` instead of changing the main document each time.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_filename_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\getallquestions}{m}{%
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_filename_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_filename_clist {\include{##1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getallsolutions}{mm}{%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_filename_clist {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {##1}
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {#2}
    \include{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{filecontents}{Ass1.tex}
This Ass1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ass2.tex}
This Ass2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ass3.tex}
This Ass3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{Ans1.tex}
This Ans1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ans2.tex}
This Ans2
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{Ans3.tex}
This Ans3
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\getallquestions{Ass1, Ass2, Ass3}

\getallsolutions{Ass}{Ans}


Different order:

\getallquestions{Ass3, Ass1, Ass2}

\getallsolutions{Ass}{Ans}


\end{document}
```

**Update -- some improvements**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \g_filename_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\getallquestions}{m}{%
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_filename_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_filename_clist {\include{##1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\getallsolutions}{mm}{%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_filename_clist {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {##1}
    \tl_replace_once:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {#2}
    \include{\tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl}
  }
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{filecontents}{Ass1.tex}
This is Ass1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ass2.tex}
This is Ass2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ass3.tex}
This is Ass3
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{Ans1.tex}
This is Ans1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Ans2.tex}
This is Ans2
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{Ans3.tex}
This is Ans3
\end{filecontents}



\begin{document}

\InputIfFileExists{order}{}{}

\getallsolutions{Ass}{Ans}


Different order:

\InputIfFileExists{differentorder}{}{}

\getallsolutions{Ass}{Ans}




\end{document}
```

`order.tex`

```
\getallquestions{Ass1, Ass2, Ass3}
```

`differentorder.tex`

```
\getallquestions{Ass3, Ass1, Ass2}
```

Comment: More sophisticated solutions can be made if the settings are settled ;-)

Comment: How can I load the order from said `order.tex`?

Comment: @user3774215: See the update please!

Comment: SO MUCH LOVE.  This is going to make the next week (and then ensuing years) much easier.

Comment: @user3774215: If this is the solution, please consider to accept my answer then